# Is my VHDL sentence allowed?

Tags: syntax, vhdl

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164_unsigned.all;

ENTITY alu IS
    PORT (a: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0);
          b: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0);
          operation: IN INTEGER (1 TO 10);
          result: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0);
    );

ARCHITECTURE arch-alu OF alu IS
    SIGNAL arith, logic: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0);
    BEGIN
----rest of the code which give values to arith and logic----
    WITH operation SELECT
        result <= arith WHEN (1 TO 5),
                  logic WHEN (6 TO 10);
END arch-alu
```

My query is: Can I put a range after WHEN (as in the code), or I have to specify one by one each possibility of the signal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://tams-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/vhdl/tools/grammar/vhdl93-bnf.html the syntax you've used is permitted by VHDL '93 (the productions to look at there, in order: selected_signal_assignment, selected_waveforms, choices, choice, discrete_range, range) except that the grammar there doesn't seem to allow for the parentheses around the ranges. See also http://www.vhdl.renerta.com/source/vhd00063.htm (which again has no parens around the ranges).

Answer (score 3):

You can use ranges in choices but you should omit the parentheses.

Not that your code fragment contained a lot more errors than just the superfluous parentheses. You had a missing `end entity`, a superfluous semicolon at the end of the port declaration, and incorrect integer port declaration,... A good VHDL IDE, such as [Sigasi HDT](http://www.sigasi.com), would help you catch these immediately.
[image]
Corrected fragment:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY alu IS
    PORT (a: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0);
          b: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0);
          operation: IN INTEGER range 1 TO 10;
          result: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0)
    );
end entity;

ARCHITECTURE arch_alu OF alu IS
    SIGNAL arith, logic: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0);
    BEGIN
--rest of the code which give values to arith and logic----
    WITH operation SELECT
        result <= arith WHEN 1 TO 5,
                  logic WHEN 6 TO 10;
END arch_alu;
```